# Admins getting system emails with state=disabled

Tags: joomla-3.x, administrator, emails

I have several Super Admins built into my design, I use them for support from multiple systems. Each has a different email address that I receive emails from.

The problem is that ALL of my super admins are getting system notifications, even though their account is set to: Receive System Emails: No

I have checked the database (searching for a particular email) and even the setting in the DB is set to '0'.

Searching on google provides no result either (they REALLY need to archive the 1.5 stuff).

Anyone have any thoughts on this?

Comment: Honestly I don't know, but somebody might just have had the idea that super admins should be getting any email there is - mails might be going out to any user in the super admin group regardless of the setting. I can't check right now, this is merely a suspicion.

Answer (score 1):

I guess that the extension sending notifications is only checking sendEmail. Try to disable 'Receive System Emails' in Super Admins.

Comment: They are - confirmed in DB as well, thanks @Anibal